# What's happened to post formatting?

Tags: support

Posts look different: the most immediate and obvious change is that line-spacing has changed. Quotes are now indented a bit more, too.

Old (from [here](/questions/13764)):
[image: Previous formatting, close spacing]

New:
[image: New formatting, wider spacing]

What just happened?

Comment: I keep on trying to hover over quotes to make them less grey, instinctively, as if they were heavily downvoted answers  :/  Did anyone else notice that?

Answer (score 7):

SE have implemented a new formatting regime which has also included changes to spoilers (which now require a click rather than hover, so they're more consistent across platforms).

All the gory details are on MSE: [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting)

<sub>*This question and answer is provided purely as a pointer to the main article as not everyone will see the Featured post link.*</sub>